# Problem when splitting command with backslash in unix prompt

Tags: shell, command-line, ksh, prompt

I often use the space-backslash combination ( ) to split a command and its parameters into various lines and make it more readable:

```
/home/user> ls -ltra \
> file1.txt \
> file2.txt
```

Recently I used an instruction with a similar format on my terminal window.  Since I was going use the same files in various instructions, I decided to highlight\copy the whole command with my mouse and paste them in an open editor.
Unfortunately,

1. I only highlighted with my mouse the two file lines and
2. pasted them by mistake into the same terminal window:

Like this:

```
/home/user> > /home/user/file1.txt
> > /home/user/file2.txt
```

They system thought I was overwritting the files.  The data was lost.  Fortunately, there was backup!

Now my question:

Can a terminal session be re-configured so it uses a symbol, other than the > sign, at the start of a split command?  Something which won't have such horrendous consequences.

Example:

```
/home/user> ls -ltra \
# file1.txt \
# file2.txt
```

### UPDATE

I am using Korn shell (/usr/bin/ksh) on a Solaris server.
Korn is the company's default shell.

Comment: Just tried changing the PS2 variable to '# ' and it works in Korn.  Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `sh`-compatible shell (like `bash`), that `>` prompt is called the "secondary prompt". It's set by the value of the `PS2` variable, just like `PS1` sets the normal prompt.

You should be able to change it to `#` pretty easily:

```
PS2='# '
```

You might want to put that into your `~/.bashrc` (or whatever the equivalent is for whatever shell you're using).

Answer (score 2):

It's not based on "the system".  It's based on your shell.

In bash or other Bourne shells

```
   PS2    The  value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used as
          the secondary prompt string.  The default is ``> ''.
```